# How to add an iterator to each name value of each element in a cloneNode?

Tags: javascript

Suppose I have:

```
    <div id="addNewMenuElementPart2">
    Imagine a lot of elements here with a name= tag.
    </div>
    <div id="addNewMenuElementPart3Optional"></div>
```

And the following Javascript method to make a copy of all the elements in `addNewMenuElementPart2` again and again when the user presses a button inside `addNewMenuElementPart3Optional`:

```
    function addMoreItems() {
       var button = document.getElementById('addNewMenuElementPart2');
       var copy = button.cloneNode(true);
       document.getElementById('addNewMenuElementPart3Optional').appendChild(copy);
    }
```

The problem is it is creating each element with the same `name=` tag. But in order to submit this in a POST request, it would be helpful to have an iterator on each of the proceeding elements on their name tag.

I tried:

```
  n = 1;
  function addMoreItems() {
     var button = document.getElementById('addNewMenuElementPart2');
     var copy = button.cloneNode(true);
     copy.setAttribute(name, name + n.toString())
     window.alert(copy.name);
     document.getElementById('addNewMenuElementPart3Optional').appendChild(copy);
     n++;
  }
```

And other solutions but not working; it says: `InvalidCharacterError: String contains an invalid character` (???)

Updated (Still not working):

```
  n = 1;
  function addMoreItems() {
     var button = document.getElementById('addNewMenuElementPart2');
     var copy = button.cloneNode(true);
     var name = button.getAttribute('name');
     var copy = button.setAttribute(name, n);
     window.alert(copy);
    //window.alert(button.getAttribute('name'));
     document.getElementById('addNewMenuElementPart3Optional').appendChild(copy);
     n++;
  }
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] (you get a badge!) and read through the [help], in particular [*How do I ask a good question?*](/help/how-to-ask) Your best bet here is to do your research, [search](/help/searching) for related topics on SO, and give it a go. ***If*** you get stuck and can't get unstuck after doing more research and searching, post a [mcve] of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck. People will be glad to help.

Comment: Just retrieve the `name` attribute of `copy`, and increase it by one before re-setting it?

Comment: @iArcadia I tried that. Check above.

Comment: You had `copy.name = '1';` when I wrote my comment. And it is not working because that's not the correct way to set an attribute. Use `setAttribute()` instead. You may also have to convert it into a number if you want a correct increasing.

Comment: @iArcadia I upated my post.

Comment: You did `setAttribute(name, ...)` but the `name` variable is undefined. The first parameter need to be a string. Then, I didn't talk about converting `n` into a string, but rather converting your `name` attribute into a number.

Comment: @iArcadia I have this now:

Comment: Actually - please see updated post.

Comment: I am doing a window.alert to test things.

Comment: `button.setAttribute('name', \`${name}-${n}\`);`, if you want to update the `name` attribute, you need surrounding quotes, as for `getAttribute()`. I also corrected the value that will be inserted.

Answer (score 0):

```
n = 1;
var name = "randomName";
  function addMoreItems() {
     var button = document.getElementById('addNewMenuElementPart2');
     var copy = button.cloneNode(true);
     copy.setAttribute(name, name + n.toString());
     window.alert(copy.name);
     document.getElementById('addNewMenuElementPart3Optional').appendChild(copy);
     n++;
  }
```

1. Missing semi-colon after copy.setAttribute(name, name + n.toString())
2. Variable "Name" is not set.

You can use document.querySelectorAll to iterate through your elements after you have cloned them. This code is copying 3 at a time, because they all have the same name, however I assume you have that worked out since that isn't part of your question.

Lastly, here is how I do I add unique attributes for my own projects. Using Jquery.

```
var abcElements = document.querySelectorAll('input');
// Set their ids
for (var i = 0; i < abcElements.length; i++){
    $('input[i]').attr('name', 'exampleName' + i);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you didn't provide all your HTML code, I provide you a simple working example of you are trying to achieve.

I put many comments through the code snippet hoping that this will be understandable for you.

When you'll run the snippet, click on the "*Log my name attribute*" buttons to display their `name` attribute. You'll see that they are incrementing.

```js
// Attaches on click the function which will add new <button.log-name>.
document.querySelector('#add').addEventListener('click', onClickAdd);
// Just for testing.
document.querySelector('.log-name').addEventListener('click', onClickLogName);


// Will add a new <button.log-name> when <button#add> is clicked.
function onClickAdd() {
  // Number of already existing <button.log-name>.
  const n = document.querySelectorAll('.log-name').length,
  // The node that will be cloned.
    templateNode = document.querySelector('.log-name'),
  // The clone node.
    cloneNode = templateNode.cloneNode(true);
  
  
  // Updates the [name] attribute of the clone to 'button-X'.
  // 'X' being 'n + 1'.
  cloneNode.setAttribute('name', `button-${n + 1}`);
  
  // Appends the clone after all existings <button.log-name>.
  templateNode.parentElement.appendChild(cloneNode);
  
  // Just for testing.
  cloneNode.addEventListener('click', onClickLogName);
}


// Just for testing.
// Will log the [name] attribute in the console of the clicked element.
function onClickLogName() {
  console.log(this.getAttribute('name'));
}
```

```css
.border {
  margin: 3px;
  padding: 3px;

  border: 1px solid #000;
}

button {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <button class="log-name" name="button-1">Log my name attribute</button>
</div>

<div class="border">
  <button id="add">Add a button</button>
</div>
```